# Does Django send the signal pre_init/post_init when instances are loaded by a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to call an instance method on each instance loaded by a queryset. Can I use the pre_init/post_init signals for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, pre_init/post_init is sent even when instances are created from querysets.

Don't take my word for it, try it e.g.:

```
def pre_init_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'pre_init', sender, kwargs
pre_init.connect(pre_init_callback)

def post_init_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'post_init', sender, kwargs
post_init.connect(post_init_callback)
```

Will output something like:

```
In [5]: list(Profile.objects.all())
pre_init <class 'testapp.models.Profile'> {'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x15e6450>, 'args': (1, False, None), 'kwargs': {}}
post_init <class 'testapp.models.Profile'> {'instance': <Profile: Profile object>, 'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x15e6490>}
pre_init <class 'testapp.models.Profile'> {'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x15e6450>, 'args': (2, False, None), 'kwargs': {}}
post_init <class 'testapp.models.Profile'> {'instance': <Profile: Profile object>, 'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x15e6490>}
Out[5]: [<Profile: Profile object>, <Profile: Profile object>]
```